# SSIS is overwriting excelfilepath expression with user variable on first pass through for each loop

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have searched everywhere for an answer to this so I am hoping someone out there can help.

I am trying to follow the steps laid out for importing data from multiple excel files in SSIS.  I have several excel 2010 files in a directory and am trying to move them into a SQL Server 2008 r2 Database.  I have followed all of the directions for doing this with a For Each (File) Loop.  I have set the collections information and am using the User::Filename variable to pull back the Fully Qualified filename.  The problem I have is that when I check the properties of my excel connection manager-->click on expressions-->modify excelfilepath by setting it to @[User::Filename], SSIS immediately overwrites the property with the new value which is blank (the first time).  This then causes my package to fail during execution because there is no filename to go to in the connection.

I have set the delayvalidation property to True on the package, the dataflow and the excel connection and this does not fix the problem.  I have also tried to put a fully qualified filename into the User::Filename variable during initialization and this does allow me to process a few files but then gives me a locking error when SSIS tries to re-read the file that I put in during initialization.

I have not found anything like this on the net yet...Hopefully, someone out there has seen this.

Comment: are you modifying the excelpath within the "property expression editor" that pops up when you click on ellipsis at the right of the 'expression' text box? or directly on the properties?

Answer (score 0):

I would split this SSIS package into two.  The master package would go as deep as the For Each File Loop, but would not include the Excel Connection Manager.  The sub-package would open and process each Excel file. It would receive the Filename variable value via Configuration for a Parent Package Variable or similar.

This seems to have the effect of "closing" the excel connection after each file is finished.

I also prefer the OLE DB driver from the Access Database Engine over the native SSIS Excel connection.